# Maven install project automatically when pressing F11 on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, m2eclipse

I have a maven project in Eclipse. Everytime when I need to do `maven install`, I have to right click on the project/POM and select `maven install`. But when I press `F11`, it shows me a list of `Run As` possibilities, which again I need to select `maven install`:

[image]

How can I make it automatically select `maven install` as default whenever I press `F11` or the `run button`?

Comment: One question: Why do you need `mvn install` ?

Comment: Well, i think that is what I should do everytime to produce the artifact (.jar file)

Comment: Not a maven guy. Should I do something else?!

Comment: Only if you need to consume the resulting jar file by another project outside of your IDE or to deploy it to somewhere..otherwise you can work without it.. If you just want to check your build a `mvn clean package` is sufficient.

Comment: oh yes. I need to deploy the jar file later.

Comment: Ah Ok than it's ok to use `mvn install`...by deploy you mean to a applilcation server/ etc. ?

Comment: Yes later to an AWS instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try these steps:

1. Go to `Window` -> `Preferences`.
2. In the left top corner there is a text field type `keys` in it as shown below:

[image]

3. Then type `install` on the text box available on the right side then select `Run Maven Install` as shown below:

[image]

4. Then there is a lable with `Binding` below. Select the shortcut keys that you want to use for `mvn install` as shown below:

[image]

Here `Ctrl+M` is the shortcut key that I used. Don't forget to click on `Apply and Close` button. It should work.

Comment: Good keys have conflicts though! But that is good enough. Thanks!

Comment: @TinaJ you can use any keys as per your choice. Thanks for accepting my answer.

Comment: Sure. Wondering if there is any ways to *run* the .jar file from inside eclipse? I open a terminal and run it outside manually `java -jar myjar.jar`. I want to do it in eclipse.

Comment: @TinaJ you can post another question and here in comment add the link to that question there I will answer to your this question because here It is not possible to answer.

Comment: @HernaldoGonzalez glad I could help you :)